Linear Algebra- Jordan Chain Mechanism
thank you for spending time trying to help.
Say $V$ is a finite linear space over $F$ field.
Say $T$ is a linear operator of V (contained in $HOM(V,V)$.
Let’s consider $T$ is $nilpotent$ with nilpotency index $k$.
Lets define:
$dimV = n$
Let’s also define:
$V^i = Ker[T^i]$ whereas $ 0<=i<=k $
Lets consider $B$ a proper Jordan chain $basis$ which presents $T$ as a jordan matrice.
Say $U$ as a subspace of $V$, defined as:
$U = orb_T(v) = {[T^{m-1}](v), ……, T(v),v]}$ whereas $m<=k$
Under this logic and condition structure I have a question discussing related to direct sum, which i'd like to split into two parts.
First part defines $m = k$ and states that when that happens - you can find a $T$ - variant subspace $W$ that adds to $U$ as a direct sum of $V$, hence:
$W (+) U$ = $U (+) W$ = $V$
The proof is demonstrated by defining $B_1$ as the basis of $U$ and by defining
$W$ = span ${B / B_1}$
Hence "W" is the subspace spanned by the remaining Jordan chains apart from U.
I completely understand and agree with the reasoning thus far.
Then comes the second part of the question whereas they change the condition of $m$ such that:
$1<=m < k$ ($m$ can't be equal to $k$)
Means $dimU < k$
And they claim that in this particular case it’s guaranteed that $W$ as we defined it cannot be found ( A $T$ -variant subspace that also adds up to $U$ as a direct sum).
The way they were proving this was with a counter - example which presents a specific $T$ whose Jordan identity is
J_k(0) -
the deriviative operator defined
T: F[X] -> F[X] , T[P(x)] = P'(x)
But then shows that given U represents a smaller Jordan chain than k, the identity of:
$[T]_B = diag(J_m(0), J_2(0) )$
Whereas $J_2(0)$ represents another Jordan matrice contained inside the general one (Not necessarily a basic one),
hence $dimW = k-m$.
They claim that given $T$ is proven to be presented by $J_k(0)$ this reflects a contradiction with singular jordan identity for $T$ (up to inner order of the matrice itself).
Their counter - example is legit and I accept it. However , I can't grasp the intuition why it is happening. Generally, why should a smaller than $k$ jordan chain prevent from finding a $T$-variant space to add to $V$ as a direct space.
And another question is considering that they are right, should we limit the condition to operators whose Jordan's matrice isn't $J_k(0)$,
what's happening then?

Please use mathjax to format your post. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
